# How to communicate a progressText from a QtConcurrent::run function (or similar) to a QFutureWatcher?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, progress, qtconcurrent

If I launch some function for asynchronous execution using `QtConcurrent::run`, and am monitoring the returned future using a `QFutureWatcher`, what if anything can I do in that asynchronously executing function to communicate some progress text back which will result in the `QFutureWatcher` firing its `progressTextChanged` signal?

ie what I want to do is *something* like:

```
void fn() {
  ???->setProgressText("Starting);
  ...
  ???->setProgressText("halfway");
  ...
  ???->setProgressText("done!");
}

QFutureWatcher watcher;
connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(progressTextChanged(const QString&)), &someGuiThing, SLOT(updateProgress(const QString&)));
connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(finished(), &someGuiThing, SLOT(doStuff()));
QFuture<void> future=QConcurrent::run(fn);
watcher.setFuture(future);
```

**However**, **big problem**, the QtConcurrent::run [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtconcurrent.html) clearly states

> Note that the QFuture returned by QtConcurrent::run() does **not support**
>   canceling, pausing, or **progress reporting**. The QFuture returned can
>   only be used to query for the running/finished status and the return
>   value of the function.

So what's the simplest thing I can do which will get me something functionally equivalent to what the above is trying to do?  Do I have to abandon `QtConcurrent::run`? `QFuture`?  Both?  (And go back to `QThread` and queued connections?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QFuture returned by QtConcurrent functions like `QtConcurrent::mappedReduced()` have progress information provided by the progressValue(), progressMinimum(), progressMaximum(), and progressText() functions. Unlike `QtConcurrent::run()` which does not provide such a thing automatically.

`QtConcurrent::run()` does not provide progress information automatically like `QtConcurrent::mappedReduced()`. But you can have your own progress reporting mechanism using signals. I don't think there is any other way which is straightforward.

Comment: OK, but then what do I actually call in `fn()` to get the progress information to update?  Obviously it'll need to have something passed into it... but what?  There seems to be a QFutureInterfaceBase which has progress info setting methods, but QFuture doesn't actually inherit it.  Hmmm... obviously the next step is to look at the `QtConcurrent::mappedReduced()` implementation and see how it does it...

Comment: I think using signals to report progress is the most convenient way when using QtConcurrent::run().

Comment: Yes that's what I ended up doing: sending status messages out of the concurrent function using QMetaObject::invokeMethod with QueuedConnection to a slot monitoring its progress (actually, BlockingQueuedConnection seemed to result in smoother display... I send a lot of messages).  Bit more on the context at http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/41012/#174738

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `QFutureWatcher` with `QProgressDialog` like in my example:

```
void hole_mark::get_frames_with_progress(const QString& movie, const QString& output) {
    Ptr<cv::VideoCapture> source = makePtr<VideoCapture>(movie.toUtf8().constData());

    auto frames = (int)(source->get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT));

    QProgressDialog dialog(tr("Importing frames: %1...").arg(frames), tr("Cancel"), 0, frames, this);
    dialog.setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);

    QFutureWatcher<void> futureWatcherProgress;
    QFutureInterface<void> promise;
    QFuture<void> future = promise.future();
    promise.reportStarted();

    QObject::connect(&futureWatcherProgress, SIGNAL(finished()), &dialog, SLOT(reset()));
    QObject::connect(&dialog, SIGNAL(canceled()), &futureWatcherProgress, SLOT(cancel()));
    QObject::connect(&futureWatcherProgress, SIGNAL(progressValueChanged(int)), &dialog, SLOT(setValue(int)));
    QObject::connect(&futureWatcherProgress, SIGNAL(progressRangeChanged(int, int)), &dialog, SLOT(setRange(int, int)));
    QObject::connect(&futureWatcherProgress, SIGNAL(progressTextChanged(const QString&)), &dialog, SLOT(setLabelText(const QString&)));

    futureWatcherProgress.setFuture(future);
    promise.setThreadPool(QThreadPool::globalInstance());

    auto runnable = QRunnable::create([&, frames, source]() {

        promise.setProgressRange(0, frames);
        promise.setProgressValue(0);
        cv::Mat m;

        int frame = 0;

        while (!future.isCanceled()) {
            *source >> m;

            if (m.empty()) {
                break;
            }

            promise.setProgressValueAndText(++frame, tr("Importing %1 frame from: %2...").arg(frame).arg(frames));

            qDebug() << "frame: " << frame;
        }


        promise.reportFinished();
    });

    promise.setRunnable(runnable);

    QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(runnable);

    // Display the dialog and start the event loop.
    dialog.exec();

    futureWatcherProgress.waitForFinished();

    // Query the future to check if was canceled.
    qDebug() << "Canceled?" << futureWatcherProgress.future().isCanceled();
}
```