# how to use signals and slots with QtConcurrent::run and QFutureWatcher

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtconcurrent, qfuturewatcher

I'm trying to copy files with the progress bar, I have a method that works with `QtConcurrent::run` but when I connect to progressBar nothing happens but the file is copied successfully. I would like to know what is wrong with my code and how to fix that thank you
below we have my copy method and how I connect `signals and slots.`

```
QProgressDialog       progressDialog;
QFutureWatcher<void>  futureWatcher;
QObject::connect(&futureWatcher, SIGNAL(progressRangeChanged(int,int)), &progressDialog, SLOT(setRange(int,int)));
QObject::connect(&futureWatcher, SIGNAL(Value(int value)), &progressDialog, SLOT(setValue(int)));
QObject::connect(&futureWatcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::finished, &futureWatcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::deleteLater);
QFuture<void>  future = QtConcurrent::run([&, this, listu]() -> void
{
    copia(listu.at(i), desPath);
});

futureWatcher.setFuture(future);
progressDialog.exec();
futureWatcher.waitForFinished();
```

the copy method

```
void BackgroundContextMenu::copia(QString src,QString dest)
{
//QFile::copy(src,dest);
QFile Src(src);
QFile dst(dest);

      int chunkSize(256);

      if(Src.exists() && Src.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly) ){
           QByteArray dataToCopy = Src.readAll();
           if(dst.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
              
               int index(0);
               while(!Src.atEnd()){
                      QByteArray data = Src.read(chunkSize);
                      dst.write(data);
                      index+=chunkSize;
                    emit Value(index*100/Src.size());//current file copy progress


               }
               Src.close();
               dst.close();

             }
```

Comment: What is this? `SIGNAL(Value(int value))`

Comment: Check [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438044/how-to-communicate-a-progresstext-from-a-qtconcurrentrun-function-or-similar), your code (because of your assumptions) is wrong in many places.

Comment: Do you not see any error/warning messages at the console?  [`QFutureWatcher`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfuturewatcher.html#signals) has no signal named `Value`.  If you use the new signal/slot syntax mistakes such as this will be caught by the compiler.

Comment: @G.M. if using macro `SIGNAL`, there won't be such warning. That's why after Qt5 using `&class::function` is suggested instead of using `SIGNAL(function)`

Comment: @LouisGo Using the `SIGNAL` macro should result in a runtime warning being output on the console.  That's the message to which I was referring.